# Facebook page auto poster PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I try to create Facebook page auto poster, but syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in
```

Line:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
```

All code:

```
<?php
require_once("Facebook/autoload.php");
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id' => 'app_id',
 'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
 'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);

//Post property to Facebook
$linkData = [
 'link' => 'www.yoururl.com',
 'message' => 'Your message here'
];
$pageAccessToken ='my_page_access_token';

try {
 $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you on? If you are on anything below 5.4, replace the [] syntax with array().

e.g.:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
 'app_id' => 'app_id',
 'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
 'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php